# printf returning 6422044 for the value of variable

Tags: c, printf, scanf

**Question**

Basically, I have a simple C code to return the value of a variable, but, if I change the `&` of the `scanf()` and the printf the returned value of variables is changed. What is the technical explanation for this event?

**(input: 3) printf returning: 3**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int x = 1;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

**(input: 3) printf returning: 6422044**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int x = 1;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", &x);
}
```

**(input: 3) printf returning: (nothing)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    int x = 1;
    scanf("%d", x);
    printf("%d", &x);
}
```

Comment: 1. Might be handy to check the return value from `scanf`. 2. It should be `int main`

Comment: Do you know what a "pointer" is?

Comment: `printf()` _returns_ the number of characters output - in none of these examples are you inspecying what `printf()` _returns_ - only what it _outputs_ - which is not the same thing.

Comment: You write _semantically_ different code and wonder that you get different results?  The third example probably crashed before the `printf()` because you tried to write to a most likely invalid address (0x00000001).  Avoid cargo-cult programming - actually learn the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `printf("%d", &x);`, you pass the address of `x` where `printf` expects an `int`. The C standard does not define the behavior when you do this. A common result is that the address, or part of it, is interpreted as an `int` and printed, so 6422044 may be part of the address of `x` in memory.

With `scanf("%d", x);`, you pass the `int` value of `x`, 1, where `scanf` expects the address of an `int`. The C standard does not define the behavior when you do this. A common result is that the `int` is reinterpreted as an address and `scanf` attempts to write to that address. The address 1 is likely not mapped as accessible by your process, causing your process to terminate. This would result in no output from the process and also should have resulted in some error message about program terminating. If you executed the program in an IDE, you may have missed this.

Answer (score 1):

On first code it is simple. You are storing the value in the address of x so you are mentioning `&x` and you can access the value by x.

on second code your are getting the value as i mentioned above. in printf statement you are prinintg the address of x.

Basically `&` refers to address you will see lot of them while you studying the concept **Pointer**.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `&` from `printf("%d", &x);` , it will definitely solve your problem.